# What is the Catholic understanding of 'reign with him' in 2 Tim 2:12?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, eschatology, 2-timothy

2 Timothy 2:11-13 (RSVCE) has:

> The saying is sure:
>
> If we have died with him, we shall also live with him;
>
> if we endure, **we shall also reign with him**;
>
> if we deny him, he also will deny us;
>
> if we are faithless, he remains faithful— for he cannot deny himself.

What is the Catholic understanding of *'we shall also reign with him'*?

One difficulty, if all reign, who are the subjects?

One Protestant perspective is the thinking that the subjects would be the people in the Millennial Rule of Christ; the ones that were not raptured or survived through the tribulation. Also a thought is that people would still have families and offspring born of them during that time.

---

**Ideas Board**

*sketches*

*'Let them be masters ...'* [Gn 1:26]; Joseph and Potiphar [Genesis 39:8-9 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+39%3A+8-9&version=RSVCE)*; 31 and he has filled him with the Spirit of God, with skill, with intelligence, with knowledge, and with all craftsmanship, 32 to devise artistic designs, to work in gold and silver and bronze,* [[Exodus 35:31-32 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+35%3A31-32&version=RSVCE)]; [David's Adminstration](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Chronicles+18%3A+14-17&version=RSVCE)[1 Chronicles 18: 14-17]; *'Truly, I tell you, he will set him over all his possessions.'* [cf. Lk 12:44]; [The Parable of Talents](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+25%3A+14-30&version=RSVCE); you who have followed me will also sit on twelve thrones, judging the twelve tribes of Israel [(Matthew 19:28 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+19%3A+28&version=RSVCE), *'I came that they may have life, and have it abundantly.'* [[John 10:10 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2010:10&version=RSVCE)], etc.

Also Kings Pele, Elvis, etc.

Filling the stations abandoned by the fallen angels?

King of kings; All nations shall serve and obey him (nations continue?); you are **royal priesthood**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always understood it as being connected with the Mystical Body of Christ. If we endure, stay firmly connected to the Mystical Body, then just as Christ is the King of the Universe, we are also part of that kingship by our connection to Him.

Comment: Not discounting, but that would mean 'through him' vs. with him.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. The community here prefers longer answers. Please see [Guidelines for writing effective answers](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/guidelines-for-writing-effective-answers) and [What is a well-sourced, dispassionate answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/886/what-is-a-well-sourced-dispassionate-answer) After that, please [edit] this post to make it better. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: @FMShyanguya [You need 15 rep to upvote](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [125 rep to downvote.](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Answer (score 0):

According to the vision of Brother Pacificus, the throne of Lucifer was reserved for the St. Francis of Assisi.  From this I infer that the other thrones of the fallen angels are available to other saints.

Excerpt from "The Mirror of Perfection by Brother Leo of Assisi"

> In the morning Brother Pacificus returned to him. Blessed Francis was
>   standing before the altar in prayer, and Brother Pacificus remained
>   outside the choir, also praying before the crucifix. And while he was
>   absorbed in prayer he was lifted up in spirit and rapt into heaven,
>   whether in the body or out of the body God alone knoweth; and he saw
>   in heaven very many seats, and one amongst them was raised above the
>   others, glorious to behold, adorned with splendour and many precious
>   stones, so that he marvelled at its great beauty, and wondered whose
>   seat this could be. And he heard a voice that said: "This was the seat
>   of Lucifer, and in his place will be seated the humble Francis."

Comment: That takes care of St. Francis. What about the rest in *'we shall reign with him'*?

Answer (score 0):

*This may be the answer:* **We Just don't know!**

> [1 Jn 3:2
>   (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+John+3%3A2&version=RSVCE)
>   2 Beloved, we are God’s children now; **it does not yet appear what we
>   shall be**, but we know that when he appears we shall be like him, for
>   we shall see him as he is.